# Apache VirtualHost config for frontend/backend

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have an app in `/var/www/html/myapp/` folder on a linux Centos server

inside the `myapp` folder there are two subfolders:
`backend` and `frontend`

my aim would be to make sure that if a user types:

http://123.456.789/myapp/ (obviously fake IP)

the request should be routed to

`/var/www/html/myapp/frontend/`

and that all calls containing the string `"api"` are instead routed to

`/var/www/html/myapp/backend/public/api/`

To get this behavior I'm using the following virtualHost configuration on a linux machine (Centos):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/frontend>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . / 
     </Directory>


     <Directory /var/www/html>
         Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
         AllowOverride All  
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /myapp
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /backend/public/$1 [L]
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/$1 [L]
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to http://123.456.789/myapp/ i get a 500 Internal Server Error, I checked the logs and the cause is the redirection limit exceeded

Any help will be very welcome

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Alias` in virtual host conf.

Ex.

```
Alias "/myapp" "/var/www/html/myapp/frontend/"  
Alias "/api"   "/var/www/html/myapp/backend/public/api/"
```

Or whatever serves your needs

Comment: I will try and give you feedback